# Unresolved class : Validates resource reference inside Android XML files

Tags: java, android, android-studio, android-manifest, dependency-management

I am adding a module to my project for which i have to add the activity tag in my AndroidManifest file like below:

```
<activity
    android:name="com.paytm.pgsdk.PaytmPGActiviy"
    android:configChanges="keyboardHidden|orientation|keyboard"
    android:screenOrientation="portrait">
</activity>
```

But i am getting an error `Unresolved class 'PaytmPGAcitvity` at android:name line.

I have tried to add the dependency by:

- Importing JAR as module and add module dependency in Project Structure
- Adding dependency by adding external JAR under project structure
- Invalidate cache/restart after above two methods
- Clean project

The project get build and the APK is installed but it give the following error where this PaytmPGActivity is used.

```
com.washkart.activities/.OrderDetailActivity, isShadow:false t1246}
02-28 12:39:10.070 25995-25995/com.washkart.activities
W/System.err:android.content.ActivityNotFoundException: 
Unable to find explicit activity class {com.washkart.activities/com.paytm.pgsdk.PaytmPGActivity}; 
have you declared this activity in your AndroidManifest.xml?
```

It is trying to search for activity in my base package i.e. com.washkart.acitivities where the PaytmPGActivity in located in the JAR file. How do resolve this issue so that it takes the activity from JAR module instead of the app module.

TIA

Comment: if your module  containes PaytmPGActiviy then you should not to add in your Androidmanifest file  ,it should be tag  in modules Android manifest file.

Comment: It is a JAR file, not a project. So it is does not have an AndroidManifest file.

Answer (score 2):

> check package name inside manifest and mention activity name with package name.
>   Go to File > Invalidate Caches / Restart and Invalidate and Restart.
>   restart IDE then try to run.

Answer (score -1):

In order to validate a class as an activity.Your `PaytmPGAcitvity.java` class must extend to the Activity class.

```
public class PaytmPGAcitvity extends Activity{
}
```

Comment: It extends Activity already and the code is exactly the same as you have mentioned. But it still gives an error.